# Almost sure convergence of equal weighted sum

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory, independence, probability-limit-theorems, borel-cantelli-lemmas

Let $Z_1, Z_2, ...$ be independent random variables in the same probability space defined as follows:

$$P(Z_n=n)=P(Z_n=-n)=\frac{1}{2n^2} \space \mathrm{and} \space P(Z_n=0)=1-\frac{1}{n^2}$$

Is it true that

$$\lim \frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}(Z_1+...+Z_n)  = 0 \ \text{a.s.}$$

?

I thought of using the Borel-Cantelli Lemmas, but I don't know how to calculate the probability that $$P(|Z_1 + \ldots + Z_n| \ge \epsilon)$$ where $\epsilon > 0$.

I already tried to apply Chebyshev's inequalities, but it didn't work.

Comment: May a long shot, but have you tried to apply the Borel—Cantelli lemma?

Comment: Thank you for the advice. The problem with Borel-Cantelli is, that I don't know how to calculate the probability, that the absolut value of the sum is unequal to zero (or greater than an arbitrary epsilon). I already tried to apply Chebychevs inequalities, but I'm stucked.

Answer (score 1):

Notice that the series $\sum_{n=1}^{+\infty}\mathbb P\left(Z_n\neq 0\right)$ converges, as $\mathbb P\left(Z_n\neq 0\right)=1/n^2$. This means that for almost every $\omega\in \Omega$, we can find an integer $N\left(\omega\right)$ such that if $n\geqslant N\left(\omega\right)$, then $Z_n\left(\omega\right)  = 0$. This implies that for $n\geqslant N\left(\omega\right)$, 
$$\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}\left(Z_1\left(\omega\right)+\dots+Z_n\left(\omega\right)\right)=\frac{Z_1\left(\omega\right) +\dots+Z_{N\left(\omega\right)}\left(\omega\right)}{\sqrt n}    ,$$ 
which gives the wanted result.

Two remarks:

- We did not use independence of the sequence $\left(Z_n\right)_{n\geqslant 1}$.
- The normalization $\sqrt n$ could be replaced by $a_n$ where $a_n\to +\infty$ as $n$ goes to infinity.

Answer (score -2):

Hint:

Using BCL1, it looks like we have

$$P(\liminf(Z_n \ne n)) = 1$$

$$P(\liminf(Z_n \ne -n)) = 1$$

I think we can conclude that

$$P(\liminf(Z_n = 0)) = 1 \tag{*}$$

because:

$\exists m_1 \ge 1$ s.t. $Z_{m_1} \ne m_1$, $Z_{m_1+1} \ne m_1+1$, ...

$\exists m_2 \ge 1$ s.t. $Z_{m_2} \ne m_2$, $Z_{m_2+1} \ne m_2+1$, ...

So I think for $m := \max\{m_1, m_2\}$, we have

$$Z_m \ne m, -m$$

$$Z_{m+1} \ne m+1, -(m+1)$$

$$\vdots$$

which I think is $(*)$

---

Also not sure if relevant but by BCL2, it looks like

$$P(\limsup(Z_n = 0)) = 1$$

---

As for computing

$$p_n := P(|\sum_{i=1}^{n} Z_i| > 0)$$

If you're going to use BCL2 on $\sum p_n$, assuming it converges, it looks like you'll be able to conclude

$$P(\limsup(|\sum_{i=1}^{n} Z_i| > 0)) = 0$$

$$\to P(\liminf(|\sum_{i=1}^{n} Z_i| = 0)) = 1$$

$$\to P(\liminf(\sum_{i=1}^{n} Z_i = 0)) = 1$$

This looks pretty strong to me, but I guess it'll work assuming you compute $p_n$ and $\sum p_n$ converges.

Comment: Why are you posting your answer as a succession of questions? Either you prove it, or give a hint (knowing the answer), or post comments. Here, it looks like you don't actually know what what you suggest will actually lead to... which is not suitable for an answer.

Comment: @ClementC. So you're saying I'm wrong? :P

Comment: What the hell. No, I haven't even fully read/checked your answer. It just does not look like, feel like, or appear to be a proof, or an answer. As written, it's an extended comment.

Comment: @ClementC. Okay fine how about now?

Comment: Everything wrong starting at "Also not sure if relevant but". Thinking about what the mathematical statements actually mean might help.

Comment: @Did Why is it wrong? So what if it is wrong? If the part before that is right, how am I not answering OP's question?

Comment: Where is the proof that $\frac1{\sqrt{n}}\sum\limits_{k=1}^nZ_k\to0$ almost surely, already? ...[Ooops, you did it again](https://youtu.be/CduA0TULnow?t=58), it seems (that is, posting irrelevant comments instead of correcting your appalling posts).

Comment: @Did I edited to make it a hint. So there is no proof. remove downvotes if any please

Comment: Yeah, there was no proof, contrarily to what you pretended, and now there is a misleading hint... Life is hard. // By the way, from now on, your comments containing vote-related admonestations will be ignored. You have been explained why these are ridiculous but you persist, so...